# Passportjs API Endpoint Authentication and Authorization

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Scenario:
   I want to create a passportjs application where I authenticate by sending username and password to and API endpoint. After authentication, the API respond with a session candy. Once the client receives the candy, client can make any API calls using that candy. API will check for the candy and then return with the required response.

This is required in a mobile application, where I can call API's to authenticate and then call other API's with the candy.

Is it possible with PassportJS? I know that it works for desktop environment because passporjs configures the header with session information which is stored in the browser and is added to every request.

What needs to be done to make it work for my scenario? Will the implicit addition of session work, or I need to explicitly add the session information with each query?